# How to provide context to firebaseManager using Hilt

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-context, dagger-hilt

I would like to provide context to `FirebaseManager.kt`

```
class FirebaseManager @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext val context: Context,
    firebaseFirestore: FirebaseFirestore,
    firebaseStorage: FirebaseStorage
) {
    fun uploadImage(imageFileUri: Uri) {
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog(context)
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait, image being upload")

        mProgressDialog.show()  <<< CRASH


}
```

NetworkModule

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object NetworkModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideFirestore() = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideFirebaseStorage() = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
}
```

MyInspirationModule

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
abstract class MyInspirationModule {

    companion object {
        @Provides
        fun provideInspirationFirebaseStore(@ApplicationContext context: Context, firebaseFirestore: FirebaseFirestore, firebaseFirebaseStorage: FirebaseStorage) : FirebaseManager =
            FirebaseManager(context, firebaseFirestore, firebaseFirebaseStorage)
    }
}
```

When I would like to use instead of `@ApplicationConteext` -> '@ActivityContext' hilt doesn't like it and app doesn't work. I also tried `@ActivityScope` like this

```
    companion object {
        @Provides
        @ActivityScoped
        fun provideInspirationFirebaseStore(@ApplicationContext context: Context, firebaseFirestore: FirebaseFirestore, firebaseFirebaseStorage: FirebaseStorage) : FirebaseManager =
            FirebaseManager(context, firebaseFirestore, firebaseFirebaseStorage)
    }
```

My app goes to Intent with making a photo and back to fragment and it should show dialog, but it doesn't work now it is crash. Firebase works fine it load data, but this context...

Error and crash when app use:

```
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog(context)
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait, image being upload")

        mProgressDialog.show() <<< CRASH
```

```
    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:907)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:387)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:95)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:342)
        at com.example.learningmanager.fragments.myinspiration.FirebaseManager.uploadImage(FirebaseManager.kt:31)
```

Additionaly it is my UseCase with firebasestorage

```
class AddImageMyInspirationFirebaseStorageUseCase @Inject constructor(private val firebaseManager: FirebaseManager) {
    suspend fun create(imgUrl: Uri) {
        firebaseManager.uploadImage(imgUrl)
    }
}
```

Comment: try to upload the image from the presenter or viewmodel, receiving the user action, updating the ui with the loading state to visible and, when the image is uploaded in the firebase, then hide the loading in the view.  So the use case notify to the repository upload the image in the firebase, but the manager shouldnt manage the ui state, only the presenter/viewmodel

Comment: I know for now maybe it is not that excellent solution, but I provide for all these steps like firebase, usecase, viewmodel, fragment this value:
activity: FragmentActivity and it works, but I will have in mind your answer and will try to change it later to be more clean. Thanks!

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will help, right?